# Orientation based UIView Background images

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

How to set different background images for different orientations in ios6 for iphone and ipad? Now i set image bg for vertical as follows,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ihome.png"]];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

i tired with the following coding its not even going inside the code

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];
}
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];
}
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ihome.png"]];
}

return YES;

}
```

please help me to sort it out

## edit

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
  {
// return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
 return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
 }

 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
    
          self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];

if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
   
         self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];

if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)
  
       self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ihome.png"]];
     
       
  // return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From apple doc:

"`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`
Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the view controller supports the specified orientation. (**Deprecated in iOS 6.0**. Override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods instead.)"

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)

      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];

if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)

     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lhomescreen.png"]];

if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait)

   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ihome.png"]];


return YES;
}
```

Comment: i updated my question . i tried but it doesnot fixing any prob in my code